# How thread-safe is my uniquing code?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, thread-safety

I have a small value class that I create lots of instances of. Often with the same value. This class is used as a kind of identifier, so the main use is comparing instances of this class with each other (via `isEqual:`).

To save some memory and time comparing I keep only unique instances in a `NSHashTable` and use pointer comparison instead of `isEqual:`.

So my designated initializer looks like this:

```
- initWithStuff: (NSString *)stuff;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // ... (actual initialisation code omitted)

   hash = UniquingHashTable();

   static OSSpinLock spinlock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT;
   OSSpinLockLock( &spinlock );

   id member = [hash member: self];
   if (member) self = member;
   else [hash addObject: self];

   OSSpinLockUnlock( &spinlock );

   return self;
}
```

`UniquingHashTable()` returns the global `NSHashTable` or creates it via `[NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]` if it doesn’t exist yet. The `weakObjectsHashTable` is the important bit - it stores weak pointers to the objects that automatically get removed once there is no other strong reference to that object. The initialization is thread-safe thanks to `dispatch_once`.

This works fine, peak memory usage is significantly lower and all my test cases still pass.  But I am not quite sure if I can rely on pointer-comparison to test for equality. *Is there any case or race condition where I get two distinct instances at the same time (so the pointers are different) but they still compare equal by `isEqual:`?*

#### To clarify what I have/want:

Given

```
MyClass *a = [[MyClass alloc] initWithStuff: stringA];
MyClass *b = [[MyClass alloc] initWithStuff: stringB];
```

we always have

```
[a isEqual: b] == [stringA isEqual: stringB];
```

This is not changed with the new code.

What I am trying to achieve is that also

```
[a isEqual: b] == (a == b)
```

so that I can replace the `isEqual:` with a faster pointer comparison. (Yes, I measured this, this will be significant).

For single threaded code or if I was using a `NSMutableSet` instead of a weak `NSHashTable` this always works out. I’m just not sure if there is any race condition so that I can have the case where

```
[a isEqual: b] && (a != b)
```

is true.

Comment: Also try it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you overridden `hash`?

Comment: Please not that OSSpinlock is unsafe on iOS: http://openradar.appspot.com/23896366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code should be fine, but I would suggest a handful of possible changes.   These are based on assumptions/observations and may or may not apply.

If it is possible, move the uniquing code to a class [factory] method and unique on the value of `stuff`.  That may be pseudo-code, but it would appear that `stuff` is the sole source of initialization state.   Regardless, doing so would save a pass through `alloc`/`dealloc` in the collision [cached] case.

Assuming nothing else uses `UniquingHashTable()`, move the `static` declaration of that = the `dispatch_once()` initializer into your `initWithStuff:` (or factory) method.  It makes the code clearer and less fragile (in that nothing can muck with the hashtable externally).

Use a serial GCD queue for your serialization in the cache lookup code;  queues are really cheap and often don't have to cross the user->kernel barrier to enqueue and execute a block.

The hashtable will be using a combination of `hash` and `isEqual:` to exactly determine object equality (an implementation detail, really... since a weak hashtable uses Object personality, `isEqual:` will be used as the final say to determine equality).   Thus, hash collisions should not be an issue.   If you want to ensure that two of your objects with *different* addresses are not equal, implement your `isEqual:` accordingly (where two objects that are equal *must* have the same hash, two inequal objects *may* have the same hash value).

---

The implementation of `isEqual:` generally first tests pointer equality and, only on failure, does it go down the required rabbit hole of testing internal state to ensure equality.

If you have a custom `isEqual:`, it should do the same.

Your code (as originally implemented) is already incurring overhead of a `malloc` and `free` (via `+alloc` and `-dealloc`) in the collision case.   That would be a seemingly huge amount of overhead compared to a few invocations of `isEqual:` (assuming your hash table isn't hugely collision heavy).

How are you measuring the overhead of `isEqual:` vs. pointer comparison?

Comment: Thanks, that’s some good advice. Doesn’t really answer my question though, maybe I was a bit unspecific. I added some more info to my question.

Comment: The time spent creating and uniquing those objects is not a problem, it reduces peak memory usage and for that it’s worth it. But once they are created I run an algorithm that has to compare them a lot. The `isEqual:` is not the bottleneck there, but it does show up in Instruments. If the uniquing (which I'm doing for the memory savings anyways) allows me to do the pointer comparison instead (which I am not sure of) this would be a nice bonus.

Comment: Ah -- OK.  Generally, a pretty safe assumption that someone is mis-using a micro-benchmark.  So, yeah, given the algorithm you have, there shouldn't be a race condition unless someone bypasses the -init entirely, which would likely be beyond scope.   Thus, pointer equality should be safe for this case.